# SQL to SELECT all groups belonging to a specific member ID AND all the users that belong to each group

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, the relevant parts of which are:

users

```
users.userID, users.userNickname
```

groups

```
groups.groupID, groups.groupOwner, groups.groupName
```

mapFriendsGroups

```
mapFriendsGroups.userID, mapFriendsGroups.groupID
```

To be clear, the functionality is that a primary user can create new groups which appear in the groups table.  A primary user has a list of friends (secondary users, each with their own entry in the users table) that they can add to one of their groups; this is represented by that friend's users.userID value being entered into the mapFriendsGroups.userID field of the mapFriendsGroups table. I then wrote this SQL to get the data that I want to display:

```
 SELECT `groups`.*, `users`.* FROM `groups` JOIN `mapFriendsGroups` ON `groups`.`groupID` = `mapFriendsGroups`.`groupID` JOIN `users` ON `users`.`userID` = `mapFriendsGroups`.`userID` WHERE `groups`.`groupOwner` = ? ORDER BY `groups`.`groupID`, `users`.`userLastName`
```

I handle this as a prepared statement in PHP and bind the primary user's users.userID value (which is held in a session variable) to the ?

This very nearly works but I discovered one problem - if a primary user creates a group but has not assigned any members to that group, the group will not be part of the results. I am convinced I'm doing a JOIN wrong but can't seem to get it to work.

I checked several other questions on stackoverflow (e.g. [Select all users that belong to a certain group, complicated query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983042/select-all-users-that-belong-to-a-certain-group-complicated-query) and [SQL: query get all users for a specific group and each user with all groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66693042/sql-query-get-all-users-for-a-specific-group-and-each-user-with-all-groups) ) but all of those answers seem to assume that the groups are not restricted to a subset and filtered by the current user's ID.

Anyone have any suggestions?

In case it matters, here's what I'm using to parse the data after I get it:

```
if ($r->num_rows > 0) { // If it ran OK.
    $data1 = $r->fetch_assoc(); 
    $myGroups = '';
    $currentGroup = '';
    do {  
        // check the value of the current group variable against the actual current group name
        if ($currentGroup == $data1['groupName']){
            // this is part of a prior group...
            $myGroups .= ', '.$data1['userFirstName'].' '.$data1['userLastName'];
        } else {
            // this is not part of a prior group. check if the current group variable is empty - if it is then just start a new row
            if ($currentGroup == ''){
                $myGroups .= '<tr>';
                $myGroups .= '<td><strong>'.$data1['groupName'].'</strong></td>';
                $myGroups .= '<td>'.$data1['userFirstName'].' '.$data1['userLastName'];             
            } else {
                // close the prior group then start a new row
                $myGroups .= '</td>';
                $myGroups .= '</tr>';
                $myGroups .= '<tr>';
                $myGroups .= '<td><strong>'.$data1['groupName'].'</strong></td>';
                $myGroups .= '<td>'.$data1['userFirstName'].' '.$data1['userLastName']; 
            }
        }
        // assign the current group name to the current group variable
        $currentGroup = $data1['groupName'];
    } while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r));
    // close the final row
    $myGroups .= '</td></tr>';
```

It ain't pretty, but it outputs a table of data where the users sees all of his groups (that have members in them) and who are the members (note that the creator of a group is NOT part of the group - this is important for later functionality).  Again, I just need a tweak that will let this show empty groups. It's not an error in the PHP code - I've tested the SQL directly in phpMyAdmin's SQL tool and even there I'm not seeing the groups with zero members.

I wish I could just add the creator of the group to the group - that would enable my current code to do the job - but again that's not an option for this project.

*****EDIT 01*****
Here's a sample of the data:

from the users table
userID = 5 is the primary user (the value of ? in the test query)
other userID values are 1,2,3,4,8,10,11,12

from the groups table, only those groups whose groups.groupOwner value = 5

```
groupID = 11 | groupName = BFFs
groupID = 12 | groupName = Car
groupID = 13 | groupName = Shopping
groupID = 14 | groupName = Travel
groupID = 15 | groupName = Test
groupID = 18 | groupName = Gamers
```

from the mapFriendsGroups table, the relevant rows

```
userID = 1 | groupID 11
userID = 2 | groupID 11
userID = 3 | groupID 11
userID = 1 | groupID 12
userID = 2 | groupID 13
userID = 3 | groupID 13
userID = 1 | groupID 14
userID = 3 | groupID 14
userID = 1 | groupID 15
userID = 2 | groupID 15
```

*****EDIT 02*****
I took the csv export option from phpMySQL and dumped it into a text editor, removed the irrelevant columns, and am pasting it here. Note there's 10 rows.

```
11,5,BFFs,3,Alex,Smith
11,5,BFFs,2,Ben,Smith
11,5,BFFs,1,Allison,Smith
12,5,Car,1,Allison,Smith
13,5,Shopping,3,Alex,Smith
13,5,Shopping,2,Ben,Smith
14,5,Travel,3,Alex,Smith
14,5,Travel,1,Allison,Smith
15,5,Test,2,Ben,Smith
15,5,Test,1,Allison,Smith
```

I'm trying to get this same type of output, but with an 11th row that would be:

```
18,5,Gamers,,,
```

That is, the group that has no members in it.

*****EDIT 03 - FINAL EDIT*****
I've got it working. The trick seems to be to make both of the joins into LEFT JOIN - that gives me the needed output of 11 rows, i.e. 10 rows with associated members of a group and 1 row for a group that has no members (and which has null values for the fields of userID and userName so I'll need to handle that in the PHP code that parses it... but that's trivial).

Thank you very much to all of you that contributed. I will mark as the correct answer the contribution which helped me the most to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not a relation between groups and mapFriendsGroups you should use LEFT JOIN ( and not JOIN - INNER JOIN ) for manage this case

```
SELECT `groups`.*, `users`.* 
FROM `groups` 
LEFT JOIN `mapFriendsGroups` ON `groups`.`groupID` = `mapFriendsGroups`.`groupID` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`userID` = `mapFriendsGroups`.`userID` 
WHERE `groups`.`groupOwner` = ? 
ORDER BY `groups`.`groupID`, `users`.`userLastName`
```

Comment: update your question ad a add  the sample and the expected  result as tabular text  ..  in comment the data sample are not clear  ..and avoid data sample as image...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I've edited the original question to provide some sample data.

So there's no members in valid userID values for groupID 18, i.e. the primary user (userID 5) has not added any users to groupID 18 ('Gamers') yet. 

When I run the query as you provided, I still only get 10 results, not 11; groupID 18 doesn't show up in the results in the phpMyAdmin SQL tool.

Comment: in yourr data sample i don't see  groupOwner 5 .. nor the columns name  .. try explain better ...anyway looking to yoru data sample the query with left jon should return the value 18 too

Comment: I'm using a single table for all users. The primary user that's logged into the system, i.e. the user who owns the groups we want to select, is userID 5 (taken arbitrarily; we could use a different ID but it would yield a different number of groups as each user's created groups are unique in the system).  The owner's ID (5 in this case) is a field in the groups table, i.e. groups.groupOwner  Due to a requirement of this project, the owner of a group can not be added as a member of a group that they have created, thus I have to do this in this circular fashion because of that requirement.

Comment: I understand ..  anyway as in my previous comment  looking to youe data sample the query with left join  should return the value 18 too..  (not eif you use inner join on table mapFriendsGroups

Comment: I just tried making both of the joins into LEFT JOIN and it worked that way. I'm seeing 11 rows in the output.

Comment: You need  two left join becuase  in one table where is null ref to user  ..  correct ...answer uodated

Answer (score 1):

You should use left join from the "groups" table to "mapFriendsGroups" table. That way if there is no record in the "mapFriendsGroups" you still can retrieve record from "groups" table. Here is the query:

> SELECT `groups`.*, `users`.*
> FROM `groups`
> LEFT JOIN `mapFriendsGroups` ON `groups`.`groupID` =
> `mapFriendsGroups`.`groupID`
> INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`userID` =
> `mapFriendsGroups`.`userID`
> WHERE `groups`.`groupOwner` = ?
> ORDER BY
> `groups`.`groupID`, `users`.`userLastName`

Comment: Did you just copy the other answer that was posted 6 mins earlier?

Comment: No I answered on my phone. I don’t need to copy that answer. This question is not that hard.

Comment: Yes you did copy the code as it is in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt but that isn't providing the needed results. I should see 11 rows of output - 10 rows for groups that have users and 1 row for a group without any users. Instead, I am still seeing just 10 rows of results.

Comment: Then there is no group created in the “groups” table when the primary user created a group. Please check on that.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion but there is indeed such a group. I can see it clearly in phpMyAdmin - it is groups.groupID = 18 and groups.groupName = "Gamers".  However, because there are no users in that group (and due to the requirements of this project I can't add the group's creator as a member of the groups they create) this group does NOT have an entry into the mapFriendsGroups table...

Comment: How about we simplify the query by this: select the primary user and their groups, left join to the mapFriendsGroups. Only then when you have all groups needed, left join to users table to find the other members of these groups.

Comment: Thank you. We came to the same conclusion in the other thread of comments as well.  Two left joins is indeed the answer.